# Android native front-facing camera C++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, camera

Hey I'm coding something in OpenCV. Naturally I would like the processing to be as fast as possible and based on my preliminary tests basic processing jumps from 11fps to 24 fps when using C++ compared to Java so I would like to code the app entirely in C++.

I am having trouble finding android documentation on the native environment since most of the documentation is written in Java? Right now, though, I would just like a way to access the front-facing camera of my device NATIVELY as this is pretty necessary for basic debugging in the app I'm creating.

Answer (score 0):

Got it =) 
In your native.cpp code, find:

```
        engine->capture = new cv::VideoCapture(1);
```

Change from 0 to 1